# Lifetime of a sugar session

Tags: sugarcrm

1) What is the default lifetime of session returned by `SugarCRM` login `REST` call.

2) Can storing the session be deemed a good practice?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session life is the same as the PHP session life on the server, which can be controlled somewhat via the **session.gc_maxlifetime** directive in your php.ini file.

When you say "storing" the session, do you mean trying to use it across multiple scripts. Not sure if there is a good reason to do that, mainly because of the weirdness of how PHP sessions GC. I would initialize a session for each script, or at the very least check to see if you session is valid on each call to see if you need to re-init or not.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm using the on-demand version of SugarCRM and not the CE. So, I'm not exactly sure of the session life.

Comment: Session life on OD is 2 hours, again with the caveat that the GC needs to run to actually remove the session. But seeing how much action OD gets, it's probably pretty close to that 2 hour mark.